# TypeScript extend third party library moment.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs, typescript-typings

I simply want to add a function to the prototype of the `Moment` interface which will format always the same way whenever used. 
I tried already what can be found here.

```
declare module moment {
    export interface Moment {
        myFormat: () => string;
    }
}
```

And in some other file, the implementation:

```
Moment.prototype.myFormat = ():string => { return this.format("DD.MM.YYY"); }
```

However, this is not working. I simply want to be able to call `moment(aDate).myFormat()` but I don't get it to work.

Already tried using `declare module "moment"` and some variations of `moment.Moment` but still the same.

As found in the link there is no `declare` used. But then I get the error

> 'declare' modifier required for top level element.

Comment: When you are importing moment into your file, are you importing moment or your file? e.g. `import * as moment from 'moment'` or `import * as moment from '[yourversion]'`?

Answer (score 2):

This is working

```
import moment from 'moment';
declare module 'moment' {
   export interface Moment {
     myFormat: () => string;
   }
 }
moment().myFormat();
```